# CSS: the borders don't show in IE7 but do in Firefox

Tags: css

I have this [page](http://tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/miembros/show/id/2).

```
login: maria@mail.com
password: m
```

As you can see in IE7 there isn't any border below 'Alcorcon', 'Madrid', etc. In FF yes.

Why?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older IE doesn't like the word `grey`. Change your border-bottom to:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
```

or something and it should show up.

Answer (score 1):

It's a spelling mistake from Internet Explorer.

Write "gray" and not "grey" for IE.
The hexa from "gr[ea]y" is #808080.

Anyway the worst is that sometimes IE6 understand "grey" as "green" ...